# Couchbase. need help to run the sample code

Tags: c#-4.0, nosql, memcached, couchbase, memcachedb

I have installed the Couchbase server. The screen shot of the same is as follows

Reference Image 1 ( https://docs.google.com/open?id=0B8I81mZUeK_XdUhRUkFmZ1lNdU0 )

Reference Image 2 ( https://docs.google.com/open?id=0B8I81mZUeK_XOC1Rb0N6Q29kYUU )

Now as per the instruction mentioned in the below link i have created the sample code

 
http://www.couchbase.com/docs/couchbase-sdk-net-1.1/stage1.html

Web.config of my code is as follows

Reference Image 3 ( https://docs.google.com/open?id=0B8I81mZUeK_XbFRMUnMwLWxBdGM )

port number i tried with both 8091 and 11211. But still facing the same problem. The problem is as follows

When i ran the same code->Create user ->it seems like it is getting saved. (As it is not throwing any error)

Reference Image 4 ( https://docs.google.com/open?id=0B8I81mZUeK_XUjdYRlkzQjlURWs )

When we run the login page after creating the user,I am getting user as null. (I am sure i entered the correct username and password)

Reference Image 5 ( https://docs.google.com/open?id=0B8I81mZUeK_XZ3FLclB2MjRhM0E )

Reference Image 6 ( https://docs.google.com/open?id=0B8I81mZUeK_XNU5iMHNMc1RQd2c )

Reference Image 7 ( https://docs.google.com/open?id=0B8I81mZUeK_XTjNuaWR6ZW9acU0 )

I have 2 question now

1)How to solve the above problem (Not able to set / not able to get the value)

2)Is there anyway in the admin page (http://localhost://8091/index.html), i can see the key and values?

Note:-

1) I ran with admin rights in my machine

2) No firewall issue as i have ensured to disable the firewall for testing purpose

3) In web config i have tried with both 8091 and 11211 port.

Please help me to solve this problem

My code you can download for reference from the below link

https://docs.google.com/open?id=0B8I81mZUeK_Xck9fV2t3TnFJamc

Thanks in advance

========================================

I have followed the instruction which is mentioned in the below mentioned link  also. (As per the first answer i got for this question)

http://www.couchbase.com/docs/couchbase-manual-1.8/couchbase-bestpractice-cloud-ip.html#couchbase-bestpractice-cloud-ip

You can see the same in my below screen shots

Image 8 [ https://docs.google.com/open?id=0B8I81mZUeK_XaFZOYWNIaFNIOXc ]

Image 9 [ https://docs.google.com/open?id=0B8I81mZUeK_Xdk41VWFPLTNaVU0  ]

Image 10 [ https://docs.google.com/open?id=0B8I81mZUeK_XWDVZaFc0ck5ZRnM ]

In my admin page i am getting a frequent warning message. That message you can see in my below link (screenshot). 
Might be that may be the cause. If yes how to correct

https://docs.google.com/open?id=0B8I81mZUeK_XRkNKQ05CTngxWjA

Still 
I am not able to read/write couchbase.

Comment: I can't access your screenshots, as they're not publicly accessible.  Which version of Couchbase Server is this?

Comment: Sorry. I have made the screenshot link as public. you should able to see all my screenshots now

Answer (score 0):

You may need to apply a workaround for Windows if the IP is changing, see the section here: http://www.couchbase.com/docs/couchbase-manual-1.8/couchbase-bestpractice-cloud-ip.html#couchbase-bestpractice-cloud-ip

Comment: I have followed the instruction which is mentioned in the above mentioned link. 

You can see the same in my below screen shots

Image 8 [  https://docs.google.com/open?id=0B8I81mZUeK_XaFZOYWNIaFNIOXc ]

Image 9 [  https://docs.google.com/open?Image 8 [  id=0B8I81mZUeK_Xdk41VWFPLTNaVU0 ]

Image 10 [  https://docs.google.com/open?id=0B8I81mZUeK_XWDVZaFc0ck5ZRnM ]

In my admin page i am getting a frequent warning message. That message you can see in my below link (screenshot). Might be that may be the cause. If yes how to correct

https://docs.google.com/open?id=0B8I81mZUeK_XRkNKQ05CTngxWjA

Comment: I have followed the instruction which is mentioned in the above mentioned link. You can see the same in my below screen shots Image 8 [ https://docs.google.com/open?id=0B8I81mZUeK_XaFZOYWNIaFNIOXc ] Image 9 [ https://docs.google.com/open?id=0B8I81mZUeK_Xdk41VWFPLTNaVU0  ] Image 10 [ https://docs.google.com/open?id=0B8I81mZUeK_XWDVZaFc0ck5ZRnM ] In my admin page i am getting a frequent warning message. That message you can see in my below link (screenshot). Might be that may be the cause. If yes how to correct https://docs.google.com/open?id=0B8I81mZUeK_XRkNKQ05CTngxWjA